# Find best offset between 2 sets of numbers

Tags: matlab

Imagine I have the following vectors:

```
A = [ 1 5 9 12 16]
B = [     1 4    ]
```

Now I am looking for an offset, that makes B an subset of A. In this example it would be 8, because B+8 gives numbers that are included in A:

```
A = [ 1 5 9 12 16] // same as before
B = [     9 12    ] // offset added: 1+8=9 and 4+8=12
```

Now I have one additional constraint for that: If there is no offset, that can map all numbers of a vector to those of A, than find the number that matches most of the numbers of a vector to those of A:

```
A = [ 1 5 9 12 16] // same as before
C = [     1 3  4 ]
```

The solution again would be 8, because this would map 1 and 4 to 9 and 12. 3 gets mapped to 11, which doesn't exist in A, but I have mapped as much numbers as possible to those of A.

I know how to get the best matching offset in my case: For every number b in B, calculate the difference between all numbers in A and b. The (positive) difference that occurs most often is the relevant offset. Now, what's a good way to do this in Matlab? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you compute all the pairwise differences between the elements of A and B:

```
diffs = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) x-B, A, 'uniformoutput', false));
```

Then, you need to find the most frequent number in this diffs array. Let's make a histogram first:

```
n = histc(diffs, min(diffs):max(diffs));
```

Then, find the most frequent element:

```
[~,idx] = max(n);
offset = min(diffs)+idx-1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your work! Yet didn't have the time to integrate it, but looks exactly like what I wanted: A short code doing it :-)